# Detecting Youtube Seek Event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I'm writing a Chrome extension which controls background music (Pandora, Google Music, etc) in response to Youtube events.

I'm able to detect when the video is started, paused, or stopped by adding an event listener to the player. However, the video switches states from playing to paused when seeking. This causes the background music to respond (unpauses) when the user is skipping in the video.

Is there any way to catch this click-and-drag seek event from within Javascript? A workaround (which might be the correct behavior) is to only unpause background music when the video ends--not just pauses--but I was curious if anybody had tackled something like this before.

Comment: Compare mouse x and y every 1/45 a sec

Comment: @Cole: Wow, that seems like a horrible hack. Why shouldn't the mouse move in that way during a "regular" pause?

Comment: @NiklasB. If the mouse moved for say 3 consecutive frames, they are seeking, else pause/play

Comment: @Cole: That logic will break if someone moves the mouse while pressing space to pause the video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeking is normally a quite a short event, so make the music only start up again after a few seconds have elapsed after the player is paused.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing. I was just hoping someone else had trickier ideas. Ah well.